# how to pass array using url with php

Tags: php, url

Im trying to pass the ArtistNumber variable from my array in the url but when i put the variable name it is missing from the url... I'm a little lost.

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ArtistNumber'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td> <a href="test.php?name='. $row['ArtistName'].'">Join</a></td>';
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<td><div id=" . $row['ArtistNumber'] . "></td>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: But in the cell you can see `ArtistNumber`? Inspect the `a`
 tag using the dev tools in your browser. Can you see the value there?

Comment: What do you mean "missing"? Is it in page source? If it is, even some redirection can be made. You should of course make sure, that you have in your table `ArtistName` column

Comment: please make sure this variable is set. do print_r($row);

Comment: also paste the sql here also do the print_r or var_dump

Comment: most probably the value of artist name has been somewhat truncated, try wrapping it with urlencode

Comment: Thank you Wumm, i can now see the value after using urlencode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. Personally, I recommend passing IDs instead of Strings as identifiers in URL but since you are passing name, the only enhancement you can make is to `urlencode()` your artist name:

```
echo '<td> <a href="test.php?name='. urlencode($row['ArtistName']).'">Join</a></td>';
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, with a slight change, i had put artist name instead of number. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are you passing  `$row['ArtistName']` that way you have to pass `$row['ArtistNumber']` from url.

```
echo '<td> <a href="test.php?name='. $row['ArtistName'].'">Join</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is fine. 
Here is my code which works fine.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<tr><td>' . getHomeTeamGoals($con, $row['HomeTeam']) . "</td>";
            echo '<td>' . $row['HomeTeam'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['FTHG'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['FTAG'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="index.php?awayteam=' . $row['AwayTeam'] . '"> test</a></td>';
            echo '<td>' . getAwayTeamGoals($con, $row['AwayTeam']) . '</td></tr>';

        }
```

You're trying to pass the ArtistName, not ArtistNumber to the URL. So if the URL changes to:

```
test.php?name=
```

It has an empty value in the database. Check the values by echoing out the data to your page and you will find your answer. The code is perfectly fine.